# testing blobs individually in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

i have image that contain many blobs . my problem is that how to test each blob individually by masking it up on the original image?!
i tried this code but i did not know how to complete it

```
labelledImage = bwconncomp(segmentedimage);             
stats = regionprops(labelledImage, 'all');
centroids = cat(1, stats.Centroid);
[row ,col] = size(centroids);
for i = 1 : row 
    areaMatr(i) = stats(i).Area; % gives area for each blob in your image

   % what i have to put here for testing the blob and masking it out over the 
   % original image? any help?
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be more prudent to use [`bwlabel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html) instead, which assigns a unique ID to each unique blob in your image.  The first output gives you this labelling and the second output gives you the total number of unique IDs / blobs in the image.  Bear in mind that this image needs to be **binary**, but given your choice of variable name, I'm assuming this to be true.

Once you find all unique IDs, you can loop through each unique ID, mask out the blob and apply `regionprops` to this blob.

Something like this:

```
%// Apply bwlabel to the image
[labelledImage, numLabels] = bwlabel(segmentedimage); 

%// For each label...
for idx = 1 : numLabels

    %// Create a mask for this particular blob
    mask = labelledImage == idx;

    %// Apply regionprops on this mask only
    stats = regionprops(mask, 'all');

    %// Use stats and mask in however way you see fit
    %// ...
    %// ...
end
```

Comment: hi rayryeng. exactly i am thinking to do that but how ?! i want to get the bounding box for each blob separately and then masking it onto the original image, then computing the number of pixels within each bounding box of masking original image then decide who the desired blob and who will be discard. kindly help as soon as posible

Comment: @saif - That wasn't part of your original question. I'm gonna leave that unanswered and let you figure that out as you haven't tried anything.

Comment: please do not be angry with me.

Comment: CC = bwconncomp(fod);  % find connected blobs and detecting its number

Comment: pixelcount=1:CC.NumObjects;      % creating a vector for saving the largest pixels number found in each blob then use it for comparing with other blobs and the large number win

Comment: [labelledImage, numLabels] = bwlabel(segmentedimage);

Comment: for idx = 1 : numLabels    %// Create a mask for this particular blob
           mask = labelledImage == idx;
           bvmask=originalimage;
           bvmask(mask)=0;
           bv1mask=originalimage-bvmask;

Comment: %// Apply regionprops on this mask only
           stats = regionprops(bv1mask, 'all');
           bb = round(reshape([stats.BoundingBox], 4, []));
           measurments=regionprops(bb,'all');
           pixelcount(idx)=[measurments.Area];

Comment: end 
       [~, index]=max(pixelcount);
       finalmask= labelledImage == index;
       s = regionprops(finalmask, 'all');
       allCentroids = [s.Centroid];
       yCentroids = round(allCentroids(1:2:end));
       xCentroids = round(allCentroids(1:2:end));
       radius=round(s.EquivDiameter/2);
       result1=SaifDrawCircle(bvobject,xCentroids,yCentroids,radius);
    end

Comment: but it give error like that                                                                                 In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be
the same.   kindly support me

Comment: be patient with me i am new with matlab

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_select_a_blob_in_binary_image_having_many_blobs

Comment: Hi rayryeng . thanks for god i solve my problem after long night and i get 99.6% accuracy from 1220 images. and i am trying to rise this ratio but after a bit rest . going to sleep. bye bye

Answer (score 0):

'stats.BoundingBox' will give you the coordinates of each blob. You can use the coordinates to mask the blob onto the original image.

Comment: you are right but i want the code to bounding each blob by box separately and then masking it onto the original image(to get only the pixels that fall within the bounding box) then computing the number of pixels within each bounding box separately finally decide who the desired blob and who will be discard. kindly answer my as soon as possible.